# WooCommerce related products erroneously showing ALL products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have my own `single_product.php` template that includes `do_action('woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart')` (when the product is variable). This shows an add to cart button as well as a select box to choose a product option (i.e. large, medium, small).

I have a cross-sell on this product and am outputting it in the template using `do_shortcode('[related_products]')` which displays related products. The problem is that it displays *all* products (not the one(s) listed in the cross-sell section of that product).

I have also tried explicitly passing in the product ID with `var_dump(wc_get_related_products(get_the_id()))` which produces an array with... you guessed it: all the products!

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you aware that related products and cross sells are not the same? 
If I understand your question and explanation, you use it interchangeably

Comment: @7uc1f3r then how would I get just the cross-sells? thanks!

Comment: Assuming you have access to `$product` -> `$cross_sell_ids = $product->get_cross_sell_ids();`